# How do scammers fake the amount of storage on USB sticks?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, memory, ssd, usb-storage

I've seen a lot of ads recently regarding usb sticks and SSD's with insane storage amounts relative to their price ($10 for 2TB etc.) Now, this is obviously a scam, but after watching a few youtube videos on it I saw that the flash drives (when inspecting its properties) actually show the fake memory size (pic from a yt video)
[Fake 2TB size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BT83f.png)

My question is: how is this done? Is this something that has to be done on the hardware end, or can anyone make their USB seem like it has terabytes of storage space? Are there any limitations to this?

Thanks up front!

Answer (score 7):

Every storage device needs to signal the host its size. With all SCSI-derived protocols (such as USB storage class) this is along the lines of `READ CAPACITY`.

The device firmware will most often answer this request truthfully, but nobody stops a firmware developer from giving a wrong (too big by far) answer.

This usually works by just ignoring bits in the upcoming `READ` and `WRITE` commands, so that when the device is used with many file systems, it will (sort of) work, until the real capacity is reached.